# Make a call in android that does not have an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I made an android app to call to a number when a message is received using broadcast receiver.
But I am getting an error no activity found to handle the intent. How can I solve this problem?

**Code is given below**

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent1.setData(Uri.parse(incno1));
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

I added the line `intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`, but this also does not solve my problem.

Comment: i run the program in emulator...

Comment: after adding the "tel:" preceding the incoming number,app works fine  in the emulator .but does not meet the requirement when running on my android phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol is incorrect. You need to do the following:

```
  callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+incno1));
```

And ensure the following permission is set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be working i am not tested:

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent1.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + incno1));
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    context.startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: what is the significance of intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

Comment: if you are start call intent from service using that!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in your xml file

```
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:phoneNumber="true"
```

add this to your text view that links directly to call.

Comment: we didn't use any activity ..then what is the importance of xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
          intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+123456"));
          startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("SampleApp", "Failed to invoke call", e);
        }

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

use permission in AndroidManifest.xml